# How to prevent CSS from another part to influence code

Tags: php, html, css

I have an `index.php` file that requires two parts: `header.php` and `footer.php`.

Both of these parts have their own CSS stylesheet (`header.css` and `footer.css`).

However, the style from footer.css influences the appearance of the elements of the header.php file. Here's a schema:[image]

I couldn't find anything on the web on how to prevent this from happening. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Are your class names the same for these elements in header and footer?

Comment: Give your classes unique names. Or, use something like `<div class="header"><h1>test</h1></div>` for your header and use `.header h1` in your `.css` to specifically target a `<h1>` within your `.header` class without interfereing with your footer.

Comment: _“However,”_ - no, not “however”, but _of course_, because that’s how CSS works. It does not matter whether you embed two separate stylesheets, or just one, or fifteen - they still apply to the _whole document_. If you don’t want your header styles to apply to your footer elements and vice versa, then you have to limit the scope by writing appropriate selectors.

Comment: @LazarNikolic yes they are. That's why I wanted to use two files instead of one. Apparently that's not possible :-(

Comment: use different class/id names to identify your tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent from influence one css class for other by changing its name. Footer css should have footer related class and header should have header related name.

Its not possible to use in php file one css class with two different output

Solution: change name of problematic CSS class.